# Combining Two Where Statements

Tags: sql

I am having difficulties combining the two statements below. I need my query to look for statement 1 OR statement 2. I can't figure out how to add an OR statement between the two. #Standard-SQL

Statement 1

```
WHERE
   (feedback IS NOT NULL OR text IS NOT NULL)
   AND rating <= 2
```

Statement 2

```
WHERE
   (rating = 3 OR rating = 4)
   AND feedback IS NOT NULL
```

Ideal Result is something like this...

```
WHERE
   (feedback IS NOT NULL OR text IS NOT NULL)
   AND rating <= 2
 OR  
   (rating = 3 OR rating = 4)
   AND feedback IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Your last WHERE is correct, because the order of precedence is NOT-AND-OR and this happens to match in your case. But of course you should follow JNevill's advice and use parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate both FULL conditions in parentheses:

```
WHERE
 (
   (feedback IS NOT NULL OR text IS NOT NULL)
   AND rating <= 2
 )
 OR 
 ( 
   (rating = 3 OR rating = 4)
   AND feedback IS NOT NULL
 )
```